# NodeJs + Express + EJS + Sequelize y duplicidad de registros

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, ejs, sequelize

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño e-commerce y para registrar las ordenes tengo un esquema de tres tablas: Producto, Producto_Transaccion y transaccion.
El metodo que guarda los datos de la confirmación del carrito esta generandome DOS transacciones en lugar de una, pero esto sucede solo cuando al final del metodo quiero enviar una vista, si en su lugar redirecciono no sucede, comparto el codigo para ver si estoy haciendo mal alguna otra cosa, si bien tengo algunas ideas de como sustituir este tema por otra solución, me resulta realmente raro lo que pasa.
En mi controlador, el metodo es este:

```
test: async (req, res) => {
    let order = {
      id_comprador: req.session.user.id,
      id_estado: 1,
      id_direccion: 1,
      fecha_compra: "2022-10-2",
      observaciones: "TEST",
    };
    let orderSaved = await db.Transacciones.create(order);
```

En la primera parte registro la transacción y en la segunda guardo en la tabla pivot el detalle de los items que la componen

```
    let idOrder = orderSaved.dataValues.id;
    let cart = req.session.cart;
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      const item = {
        id_Producto: cart[i].id,
        cantidad: 1,
        impresionesTotales: 1,
        id_transaccion: idOrder,
      };
      await db.Producto_Transaccion.create(item);
    }
    req.session.cart = [];
    // res.render("cartOrderOk", { auth: req.session.user, idOrder: idOrder }); con esta linea activa, registra dos transacciones consecutivas en la DDBB
    res.redirect('/') //en esta opcion no sucede.
  },
```

Tal como se ve, en la DDBB aparecen DOS transacciones consecutivas con la misma informacion, pero si el final lo cambio por un res.redirect no pasa.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier comentario, soy bastante nuevo en el tema y estas cosas me retrasan bastante!